# jQuery Texfill not working on all elements with same selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery [Textfill](http://plugins.jquery.com/textfill/) to make an HTML list's contents fit their container. However, when I initialize the plugin with the relevant options, the textfill plugin only "acts" on the first instance of the selector. E.g.

```
<div id='abc'>
    <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#abc').textfill({
    debug: true,
    maxFontPixels: 0,
    innerTag: "li"
});
</script>
```

Only "foo" gets resized. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gMFG/245/)

Does anyone know if there's a way to overcome this? Have I missed a certain option?

Comment: shouldn't it be `innerTag: "ul"`?

Comment: actually that resizes both the list items. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. According to $.textfill [docs](https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill) it will add :visible:first to whatever you put in innerTag

Check what happens when the first LI is hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/9VwV3/

```
<div id='abc'>
    <ul>
        <li style="display:none;">foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ah. is there any way I can harcode it then? I know for sure that the list will only have 3 items

Comment: nvm, I tried @epascarello's suggestion and it worked